# htaccess rules. Allow from specific IP and Referer only

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to add an htaccess rule that will do the following.

Allow specifc IP(s)

Allow from a specific refer (another domain)

Deny Everyone else

Denied redirected to a specific URL. (another domain)

This is a wordpress site a and thought of use htaccess unless there is another way. Thanks for you help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www\.your_domain\.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www\.another_domain\.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.another_domain.com/not_allowed_here.htm [R=301,L]

ErrorDocument 403 http://www.another_domain.com/specific_page.html
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 111.222.333.444
```

And with user in the same test:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www\.your_domain\.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www\.another_domain\.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^111\.222\.333\.444$
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.another_domain.com/not_allowed_here.htm [R=301,L]
```

Comment: ok, I added the following

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www\.xyz\.org [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://google.com [R=301,L]

order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 75.69.111.111
</IfModule>

the allow from is my IP, but get redirected to google.

Comment: If you change de name for google, I think it's normal... The rewrite was for your error page, like you ask for.

Comment: I added google.com as the redirect to test the rule, not sure what you are saying.

Comment: Sure if the referral, but my IP as noted in the allow from gets redirected.

Comment: The test was for one user and one domain referer. I edit the code for one or the other.